# Sorting text from text File

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, text-files

```
    package individual;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Individual{

        public static void getContent(Scanner inp,String[] contents){
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<contents.length;i++)
                contents[i]=inp.next();

       public static void Sort(String[] contents){
           int i,j;
           int min;
           String temp;

           //for selection sort
           for(i=0;i<contents.length-1;i++)
           {
               min=i;

               for(j=i+1;j<contents.length;j++)
                   if(contents[j].compareTo(contents[min])<0)
                       min=j;
               temp=contents[i];
               contents[i]=contents[min];
               contents[min]=temp;

           }
       }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

            String[] newAyat=new String[50];
            //read From file that i save in drive
            Scanner inFile=new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\newFile.txt"));

            getContent(inFile,newAyat);
            Sort(newAyat);

    }
   }
}
```

so when i run the program i got an error. The output is not what i want. Is there any problems with my codes. And how to print out the sorting results?

This is the question that I try to solve:
Based on the list relates , you must program can display a list of words beginning with ' a ' , ' b ' , ' c ' and so on .

Comment: Atleast first remove compile time errors.

Comment: "so when i run the program i got an error.", what errors ,please specify

Comment: run:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
 at individual.Individual.getContent(Individual.java:9)
 at individual.Individual.main(Individual.java:37)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: `NoSuchElementException ` means scanner's next() method could not could find any more input ,always use `hasNext()` before calling next

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont get it.. can you explain more??

Comment: @Ghost the error you mentioned looks like a runtime error. Were you able to compile it successfully?

Comment: no...i'm not able to compile it.. @Abdullah Leghari

Comment: hasNext() ..??@Ramanlfc

Comment: One thing I can immediately spot is ``getContent()`` function has no closing ``}`` .  You are most probably using the ``Scanner`` incorrectly.

Comment: i have make correction on that part but the the error is still the same. @Abdullah Leghari

Comment: Somebody please help me??

Comment: i have make correction on that part..but then my brain stuck....How to print the sorting result?? arghhhh.....

Answer (score 0):

```
package textconcordance;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TextConcordance {
final static int SEN_LONG=8;
 public static void getAyat(Scanner inp,String[] Sentence){
    int i;
    while(inp.hasNext()){
    for(i=0;i<Sentence.length;i++)
        Sentence[i]=inp.next();
    }
}
//sort sentence
public static void sortSen(String[] Sentence){
    int i,j;
    int min;
    String temp;

    for(i=0;i<Sentence.length-1;i++)
    {
      min=i;
      for(j=i+1;j<Sentence.length;j++)
          if(Sentence[j].compareTo(Sentence[min])<0)
              min=j;
      temp=Sentence[i];
      Sentence[i]=Sentence[min];
      Sentence[min]=temp;     
    }
}
//for print
public static void print(String[] Sentence){
    for(int i=0;i<Sentence.length;i++)
    System.out.print(Sentence[i]+",");

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String[] Sentence=new String[SEN_LONG];

    Scanner inFile=new Scanner(new FileReader("D://Ghost.txt"));

    getAyat(inFile,Sentence);
    sortSen(Sentence);

    inFile=null;
    inFile=new Scanner(new FileReader("D://Story.txt"));

    print(Sentence);

    }
    }
```